# Memory leaks caused by malloc in C

Tags: c, malloc, undefined-behavior, calloc

I'm having a hard time understanding what has gone wrong in my code. My program has a **function which reads data from a file 8 bytes at a time**.

```
char *read_64_bit_data_from_file(FILE *file, size_t *number_of_chars_read ){
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) *  8);
    *number_of_chars_read  = fread(buffer, 1, 8, file);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    printf("Length of buffer: %ld\n", strlen(buffer));
    printf("Number of chars read: %ld\n", *number_of_chars_read);
    return buffer;
}
```

The function is called as below:

```
...
size_t num = 0;
size_t *number_of_chars_read = &num;
char *message = calloc(sizeof(char), 8);
do{
    message = read_64_bit_data_from_file(file, number_of_chars_read);
}while(*number_of_chars_read==8);
...
```

Now, When I compile and run the program I get the following output:

```
Two road�B�z
Length of buffer: 14
Number of chars read: 8
s divergx<�z
Length of buffer: 14
Number of chars read: 8
ed in a x<�z
Length of buffer: 14
Number of chars read: 8
yellow wx<�z
Length of buffer: 14
Number of chars read: 8
ood, Andx<�z
Length of buffer: 14
Number of chars read: 8
 sorry I
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8
 could n
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8`
```

The problem is that the **characters written into the buffer is sometimes more than 8**, although **`fread` returns the value 8** each time.

Now, **If I use `calloc` instead of `malloc` for allocating `buffer`, I get the output as desired**. Following is the output in this case:

```
Two road
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8
s diverg
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8
ed in a 
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8
yellow w
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8
ood, And
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8
 sorry I
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8
 could n
Length of buffer: 8
Number of chars read: 8`
```

I compiled my program using GCC compiler with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags.
The compiler gave no warnings.

I ran the program through `valgrind`. Following is the output:

```
==6051== Invalid write of size 1
==6051==    at 0x10917B: char_as_binary (in 
/home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==    by 0x1091FA: string_to_binary (in 
/home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==    by 0x108EE6: main (in /home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==  Address 0x521ecf7 is 5 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==6051==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in 
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6051==    by 0x1090EE: char_as_binary (in 
/home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==    by 0x1091FA: string_to_binary (in 
/home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==    by 0x108EE6: main (in /home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051== 
==6051== Invalid read of size 1
==6051==    at 0x10900A: initial_permutation (in 
/home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==    by 0x108FA9: encrypt (in /home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==    by 0x108EFD: main (in /home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==  Address 0x521ec60 is 0 bytes after a block of size 64 
alloc'd
==6051==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in 
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6051==    by 0x1091D3: string_to_binary (in 
/home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051==    by 0x108EE6: main (in /home/saksham/Documents/DES/DES)
==6051== 
==6051== 
==6051== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6051==     in use at exit: 2,076 bytes in 172 blocks
==6051==   total heap usage: 186 allocs, 14 frees, 12,972 bytes 
allocated
==6051== 
==6051== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6051==    definitely lost: 2,076 bytes in 172 blocks
==6051==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6051==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6051==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6051==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6051== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6051== 
==6051== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6051== ERROR SUMMARY: 93 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 
0)
```

I really do not understand why malloc is behaving as such, and how using calloc fixes it. I believe my program has UB (Undefined behavior).

Please, help me understand what I'm overseeing and where am I going wrong.

Comment: You should free() whatever you malloc().  I don't see a free anywhere.

Comment: One of the differences between `calloc` and `malloc` is that `calloc` zeroes the contents of the allocated buffer, whereas `malloc` just leaves the buffer filled with junk. `strlen` and the `%s` printf format specifier expect a null-terminated string.

Comment: What I wrote above is irrelevant if you are actually filling the 8 character buffer with data from the file. You are lucky that the implementation of `calloc` you are using also ends up setting the byte after the 8 character buffer to zero, acting as a null terminator. However, you should not rely on the byte after the 8 character buffer being set to anything in particular, since accessing that byte results in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @IanAbbott Null terminating `buffer` corrected the undefined behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the C-string style functions to work (such as `strlen`), you need to reserve one byte in `buffer` for a NUL-terminator.

You are not doing this, and so formally the behaviour of your program is *undefined*. Your compiler is not picking up on this, but Valgrind is. It's also warning you about the missing `free`. Consider allocating 9 bytes, set `buffer[8]` to `0` explicitly, and make sure you don't attempt to read more than 8 bytes into `buffer`.